# How to add table elements to php array?

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have this html table. This is a simplified version (I have 100s of rows)

```
<table>
<tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Description</th></tr>
<tr><td>2013-10-22</td><td>03:05:29</td><td>DESC1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-10-22</td><td>03:05:29</td><td>DESC2</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-10-22</td><td>03:05:29</td><td>DESC3</td></tr>
</table>
```

From this all I need is following: DESC1, DESC2, and DESC3
I don't need the header part or the date and time. Only the Description column (without the title). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

use jquery

```
$('table > tr > td').text();
```

Comment: I would need it in php if possible.

Comment: In what way.. do you need to post this data or any thing like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) & [DOMXpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

For example, like this : http://codepad.viper-7.com/kvRjAO

**CODE**

```
<?php
    $html = '<table>
<tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Description</th></tr>
<tr><td>2013-10-22</td><td>03:05:29</td><td>DESC1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-10-22</td><td>03:05:29</td><td>DESC2</td></tr>
<tr><td>2013-10-22</td><td>03:05:29</td><td>DESC3</td></tr>
</table>
';

$doc = new DomDocument; // init
$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the table
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc); // init xpath for that html
$secondTDs = $xpath->query('//td[3]'); // basic xpath applied
$phpArray = array(); // init final array
foreach($secondTDs as $td){
    $phpArray[] = $td->nodeValue; // each 3rd td value in final array
}
var_dump($phpArray); // display final array for demo purpose
```

**RESULT**

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "DESC1" [1]=> string(5) "DESC2" [2]=> string(5) "DESC3" }
```